# Wired network connection active, but Firefox not detecting connection

Tags: 10.10, networking, firefox

I'm using a wired network connection that should  be manually configured. Which is working
in my parallel boot Windows XP. But in my Ubuntu 10.10 after giving same values of IP address, subnet Mask, Default Gateway and DNS Servers the wired network connection is shown as active but Firefox is not detecting any connection.

Comment: How did you configure your connection??

Comment: yes i did . after that it showed network connection active..

Comment: can you post the output of `ifconfig`

Comment: from top Network icon . edit network connection...

Comment: eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:1c:3b:da:0a  
          inet addr:192.168.5.210  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:1cff:fe3b:da0a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9829 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1547519 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:119509 (119.5 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0xb800

Comment: Are you trying to setup PPPOE connection??

Comment: are you able to ping google.com or any other site. If you are not then there is nothing wrong with firefox but with your network configuration.

Comment: really my internet provider in his site given as Internet Protocol (IP)-based, Ethernet architecture....

Comment: i m not able to ping any where

Comment: my most recent ifconfig

Comment: eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:1c:3b:da:0a  
          inet addr:192.168.5.210  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:1cff:fe3b:da0a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:76 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:9000 (9.0 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0xb800

Comment: Try this setup https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE

Comment: Please paste your /etc/resolv.conf file here. Just to make sure that DNS servers are set...

Comment: @Tony Please add your information to your question, not the comments, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Karthick I tried "help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE" . i think some thing has gone wrong from my side. now even the network icon at top also not visible.... :(

Comment: # Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.2.1
nameserver 119.235.48.3
this is /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Please post the result of running "netstat -nr".  Please add all your additional comment data to the original question - edit the question to show this vital information.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that your subnet mask is set wrong. The 192.168.x.x range of addresses are normally set up as class C networks with a mask of 255.255.255.0. It won't work correctly if you have it set wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Firefox working online? Sometimes it switches to offline and don't back to online. Check if your `File` > `Work Offline` menu is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually setting an IP address for your device.

It looks like your broadband router is 192.168.2.1, so follow these steps :

1. Right click on the network manager applet and choose "Edit Connections..."
2. In the "Wired" tab, click the "Add" button.
3. Enter a Connection Name like "My Manual Connection"
4. Click on the IPv4 Settings tab.
5. Change the "Method" to "Manual".
6. Under "Addresses" click on "Add"
7. Put 192.168.2.50 for Address.  Put 255.255.255.0 for Netmask.  Put 192.168.2.1 for Gateway.
8. For nameserver, put 192.168.1.1 and 208.67.222.222 (the second address is openDNS, a free DNS server that anyone can use).
9. Click on the "Add" button at the bottom.
10. Now activate your newly created profile - left click on the network manager applet, then choose your newly created connection.

Now try pinging your gateway with `ping 192.168.2.1`.  You should see something like this :

```
scaine@GroovyTosh:~$ ping 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=255 time=0.378 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=255 time=0.358 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=255 time=0.546 ms
```

If this works, then you have an issue with your DHCP server which is issuing incorrect CLASS B (255.255.0.0) subnet masks and might not be setting your default route correctly.

However, if this *does* work, then you should be able to run with this configuration without any issues.